# HTML5 canvas draw through dots

Tags: html, canvas

I am using HTML5 canvas to plot series of dots, using array data to plot this dots. I would like to draw smooth lines between the dots, I would like to start from the first dot to the last, like join the dots game.

I am using the following code to draw on my canvas, but I cant figure out how I would be able to draw smooth lines between the dots

```
context.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(event.offsetX, event.offsetY,5, 0, Math.PI*2);
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
```

My dots data looks something like this

```
 data = [
     [192,27]
    ,[183,55]
    ,[307,375]
    ,[192,521]
    ]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEQha.png)

Comment: if by "smooth lines" you mean curves, then maybe [`bezierCurveTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/bezierCurveTo) method can help you.

Comment: Have you tried `ctx.quadraticCurveTo()` or `ctx.bezierCurveTo()`. Curve fitting is a whole subject in its own right. Is it just a visual solution or does it need to fit constraints. You can start by learning how to create a set of point along the lines, then try running averages. It all depends on the constraints..

Comment: THis may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/33882382/3877726 it shows a smoothing method for point drawn via the mouse. Though not a very good solution if you have only a small number of points.

Comment: Thanks I haven't tried ctx.quadraticCurveTo() or ctx.bezierCurveTo(). I will look into it, I assume I can use this to create a simple join the dots app.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to use a [cubic Hermite interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation):

```
function interpolation (a, b, t) {
    var t = t * t * (3 - 2 * t);
    return a + (b - a) * t;
}
```

Looks quite smoothly: https://jsfiddle.net/nh23hhdh/

Next function make a linear interpolation (also known as [lerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)) and you'll see your original result:

```
function interpolation (a, b, t) {
    return a + (b - a) * t;
}
```

See this [page](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) for using various interpolation functions.