# HTML5-canvas. My drawing isn't smooth. I've tried everything

Tags: html, canvas

```js
var canvas;
var context;
var isDrawing = false;

window.onload = function() 
{
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 context = canvas.getContext("2d");

 canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
 canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
 canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", putPoint);
 canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", engage);
 canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", disengage);
 canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", disengage);
 context.lineWidth = 2*radius;
  context.lineJoin = context.lineCap = 'round';
};
var radius=0.5;

var engage = function(e)
{
 isDrawing = true;
 putPoint(e)
}

var disengage = function()
{
 isDrawing = false;
 context.beginPath();
}

var putPoint=function (e)
{
 if(isDrawing)
 {
  context.lineTo(e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop);
  context.stroke();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  context.fill();
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop);
 
 }

}
```

```css
body
{
 margin: 2px;;
}
canvas
{
 border: 1px solid black;
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title> Drawing app </title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="script2.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="1900" height="1000"> Your browser doesn't support canvas. </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. Please try draw something. You should see a lot of pixels.
It looks awful. I would like to line looked like this:https://sketch.io/sketchpad/. Please set there 1px and check it. It's beautiful, smooth line without pixels. I would like to achieve it.

Here is nice drawing: http://codepen.io/kangax/pen/zofsp.
But:
 - Every time you draw a new path - > canvas is cleaning. It is caused by 26th line of code.
 - When I delete it ( I mean 26th line of code ) drawing breaks :c

What I've tried?
-shadows
-gradients
-ctx.translate(0.5,0.5);
-bezier curve
And it doesen't work.

I suppose that beautiful lines I can obtain using this: ctx.clearRect(x1,y1,x2,y2).

But I have no ideas how to use it :c

I am going to create drawing app so I need smooth lines.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse data is always a but rough and there are many ways that you can smooth it. The holy grail for line smoothing is a bezier fit, but I have yet to work out how to do that in real time.

The next best thing is optimising and smoothing the line to an appox fit..

Rather than write the answer out again see the following anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/33882382/3877726

It provides a way to set the optimization and smoothing from none (sometimes you want the bumps and lumps) all the way to super smooth..